# How to associate a guacamole recording file with a historical connection record

Tags: java, guacamole

I am trying to redevelop guacamole.

I want to modify the source code of **guacamole-client** so that the screen file name can contain information such as user name, history connection id, etc., not just a fixed file name.

Can you tell me which part of the source code to modify, thank you

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more details on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to add additional information such as a user name to the screen file name by modifying the source code. This makes it easy to locate the specific file when I want to play back the recording file. But I don't know which source files need to be modified. Of course, it's best to have a way to accomplish my goal without modifying the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved.

I can use dynamic parameters when defining connection parameters

http://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#parameter-tokens

"For example, if you set the connection parameter for the recording name to "potato-${GUAC_USERNAME}", the name of the recording will vary by the user accessing it. If you access it as "guacadmin", the recording is saved as "potato-guacadmin". All connection parameters can make use of this."--mike jumper

I think I can uniquely locate a session by adding a username and begin_time to the recording file name.